# Function diagram in TikZ PGF

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to know how can I plot this diagram in TikZ PGF
[image: input of function connected to vertical line with both ends containing symbols following by a horizontal line with both ends and the top of the horizontal line containing symbols]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node(w){$w^{(\bot)}$};
  \node[below=of w](z){$z^{(\bot)}$};
  \node[right=of z](a){$a^{(2)}$};
  \draw[->] (w) -- node[right]{$L^{(\bot)}$} (z);
  \draw[->] (z) -- node[above]{$\alpha^{(\bot)}$} (a);
  \draw (z) |- +(-0.6,0.8) node[left]{$x_i$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: can we edit the last line to read -- `\draw[] (z) |- +(-0.6,0.8) node[left]{$x_i$};`

Comment: @jsbibra Thanks, this was indeed redundant.